# Ionic Angular IOS App build failing in Xcode due to distill failed error

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a blank app on my mac using the ionic cli and am now receiving this error in Xcode when trying to build:

```
Distill failed for unknown reasons. Images xcassets
```

Steps I Completed:

1. `ionic start Meddela blank`
2. `xcode-select --install`
3. `npm install -g ios-sim`
4. `npm install -g ios-deploy`
5. `ionic Cordova prepare ios`
6. Set package id in `config.xml`
7. Opened `platforms/ios` in `Xcode` from `file>open`
8. Verified ID and selected development team
9. `ionic Cordova prepare ios`
10. Selected the `iPad Pro (9.7-inch)` simulator
11. Clicked the play build button. <--- Build Failed Error Occurs

My Versions of everything I'm using:

```
XCODE VERSION: 11.1
Node Version: 12.13.0
Cordova Version: 9.0.0
Mac Version: macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta
Attempted Simulator: iPad Pro (9.7-inch)
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I am also facing same issue event latest version of ionic